# inttypes.h file not found compiling Duktape with C++ Builder and Clang

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle, duktape

I have created a simple Duktape example using [C++ Builder Seattle](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder) and follow the code in "Initialize a context" from [Duktape](http://duktape.org/).  It compiles fine when using classic mode.  If I switch to clang via unchecking Project->Options->C++ Compiler->Use 'classic' Borland compiler, I get the following error.

```
inttypes.h file not found on line 780 of duktape.h
```

If I comment out the include I get the following errors:

```
Unresolved external _va_copy
Unresolved external _fmin
Unresolved external _fmax
```

Comment: The `<inttypes.h>` header and `va_copy()` are C99 features (and I think the same is true of `fmin` and `fmax`).  Maybe you need to be compiling in a C99 or C11 mode with `clang` to have them activated.  Note that `fmin` and `fmax` are from `<math.h>` and `va_copy()` is from `<stdarg.h>`.  Or maybe you need to reconfigure Duktape when you switch compilers; it was setup to work correctly with one compiler and doesn't work correctly with the other.

Comment: I need to figure out how to reconfigure Duktape.  It has all sorts of magically auto detection #ifdefs

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would to ensure clang has `-std=c99` so that no legacy type detection is necessary.  Legacy type detection isn't always reliable.

However, if you can't use C99/C++11 for some reason, you can always edit the `duk_config.h` header directly (`duk_config.h` is present since Duktape 1.3.0), which contains all the detection logic.